# Is there any way to solve re.sub issue?

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, stop-words

[sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRmdH.png)

```
def preprocess_text(sentence):
    #Remove punctuations and numbers
    sentence = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence)

    #Single character removal
    sentence = re.sub(r"\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+", ' ', sentence)
    
    #Removing multiple spaces
    #sentence = re.sub(r'\s+'+ ',', sentence)
    sentence = re.sub(r'\s+',' ',sentence)

    return sentence

TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')

def remove_tags(text):
    return TAG_RE.sub('', text)

X = []
sentences = list(product_reviews['Görüş'])
for sentence in sentences :
    X.append(preprocess_text(sentence))

X[81]
```

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}`) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: I think you want that `+` to be a comma `,`.

Comment: What do you mean? It is not clear.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not add my question as code format.

Comment: I am getting "sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'" error..

Comment: I shared as text.

Comment: Thank you for adding the text. Please [edit] your question again and add some example data (just 3 rows would be fine) *and* the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146) you are now getting.

Answer (score 0):

After the label **#Removing multiple spaces** there is a `+` where the should be a comma between the regex pattern and the replacement string.

```
sentence = re.sub(r'\s+'+' ',sentence)
```

should be

```
sentence = re.sub(r'\s+',' ',sentence)
```

Comment: I applied your code but now I'm getting "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Please post your code as text so that we can test it.

Comment: I am getting "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" error right now, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the initialisation of certain variables. I have slighty modified it to run on it's own.

```
import re
def preprocess_text(sentence):
    #Remove punctuations and numbers
    sentence = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence)
    #Single character removal
    sentence = re.sub(r"\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+", ' ', sentence)
    
    #Removing multiple spaces
    #sentence = re.sub(r'\s+'+ ',', sentence)
    sentence = re.sub(r'\s+',' ',sentence)
    return sentence
TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
def remove_tags(text):
    return TAG_RE.sub('', text)
X = []
sentences=['test1 a &_€','test   2']
#sentences = list(product_reviews['Görüş'])
for sentence in sentences :
    X.append(preprocess_text(sentence))
print(X[0])
print(X[1])
```

output

```
test
test
```

Comment: What does 'test1 a &_€','test   2' mean?

Comment: They are the just test strings to be sure that your re.sub functions are removing the characters as desired.

Comment: They take the place of `list(product_reviews['Görüş'])` which we do not have

Comment: I got it but I'm getting TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Can you run the code in my answer exactly as I've put it?